# RecyclerView inside RecyclerView swipe to delete on child

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a really basic concept and it's probably a really easy solution that I am missing.

I basically have a `recyclerView` inside a `recyclerView`. It works perfectly and everything is smooth.

I recently decided to add a swipe to delete to the `recyclerView`s. The parent one (the outer most) works perfectly. However, when I try to do the exact same thing inside the parent `recyclerView's` (for the child) adapter it returns the wrong adapter (it returns the parent's adapter).

I think this is happening because the swipe is being detected on the parent before the child (since technically the child is part of the parent), is there a way to disable the swipe detection for the parent `recyclerView` if it's touching a child `recyclerView`? For example, in the parent I have a textView acting as a header and then the `recyclerView` right below it. Is it possible to only have the header (the `textView` act as the swipe and then the rest will go through to the child?

I followed this tutorial (https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/) subtracting the JSON and just hard coding the data for simplicity and adding a `recyclerView` inside the `adapter` and having another adapter just for a `textView` (content to make up the child's cells).

A very bizarre thing happens - when I disable the parent's swipe to delete entirely, only 1 random section works for the child. I could not find a pattern on why.

Basically to recap when I am calling my `ItemTouchHelper` class's methods, the `viewHolder` is always the parent's adapter instead of the child because the swipe is being detected on the entire parent instead of moving through to the child's `recyclerView`; is there a way to prevent or force it to go through to the child while keeping all other elements (like a `textView` header) on the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long and hard time I managed to figure it out.

Very simple for anyone else struggling:

You have two separate adapters (1 for your header + recyclerItemView) and one for your items.

In your header one (calling it section) you an interface that will watch for onSwipe and OnDrag events being called from your item's adapter.

I will post full code if people are interested. I think this approach is much better than having 1 list and some delimiter to determine which viewType to use.